# LaTeX Workshop - latexindent.pl not finding indentconfig.yaml on Windows (VS Code)

Tags: indentation, windows, vscode, latex-workshop, latexindent

I'm using LaTeX Workshop on Visual Studio Code on Windows and encountering an issue with the `latexindent.pl` script. I'm getting the following message:

> latexindent.pl didn't find indentconfig.yaml or .indentconfig.yaml (see all possible locations: https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-appendices.html#indentconfig-options)

I'm looking for guidance on how to modify my `.vscode\settings.json` file, probably by configuring the toolchain `"latex-workshop.latex.toolchain"` ([ref](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376#issuecomment-357967919)) to resolve this issue and configure the desired indentation settings for my LaTeX project.

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

- I'm using `latexindent.pl` version 3.23.5.
- My LaTeX installation is through MiKTeX.
- I've checked the [provided link](https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html) and haven't found a solution specific to my situation.
- the `defaultSettings.yaml` file is in the `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\scripts\latexindent`
- I have provided the path `"latex-workshop.latexindent.path": "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\latexindent.exe",` explicitly

Any help or suggestions on how to modify the `.vscode\settings.json` file to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `indentconfig.yaml` is optional, there's no need for it unless you want to setup your own settings which are loaded every time you use `latexindent.pl`. your log file should say something like ` Home directory is C:\Users\<....>` and that's the place to put `indentconfig.yaml`, should you wish to do so. I don't think this has anything to do with `vscode`

Comment: @cmhughes so should I just ignore the messages: `YAML reading settings
       Home directory is C:\Users\<userName>
       latexindent.pl didn't find indentconfig.yaml or .indentconfig.yaml`

Comment: It's up to you. As above, indentconfig.yaml is optional, not required

Answer (score 1):

It seems the message:

> YAML reading settings
> Home directory is C:\Users<userName>
> latexindent.pl didn't find indentconfig.yaml or .indentconfig.yaml

can be safely ignored **unless** you want to customize your indentation settings for `latexindent.pl`. These settings would then be loaded every time you use the script. You may suppress the message using the `-d` or `--onlydefault` option. This option instructs latexindent.pl to exclusively use the default settings file (defaultSettings.yaml) and ignore any user-defined configuration files.

---

**Custom Indentation with User Files:**

To create customized indentation settings, you can utilize user configuration files. `latexindent.pl` searches for these files in specific locations within the file directory or the current working directory. Alternatively, you can specify a specific file using the `-l` or `--local` option followed by the filename (e.g., `-l myyaml.yaml`). Here are some additional details about this option:

- **Valid Filenames:** `localSettings.yaml`, `.localSettings.yaml`, `latexindent.yaml`, or `.latexindent.yaml`
- **Alternative filename:** Specify a custom filename with `-l=myyaml.yaml`

**Specifying Settings Directly with `-y` or `--yaml`:**

You can define specific indentation settings directly through the command line using the `-y` or `--yaml` option followed by the desired settings in YAML format. For example, to set the `defaultIndent` to two spaces and the `maximumIndentation` to four spaces, you could use:

```
latexindent.pl -y="defaultIndent:'  ',maximumIndentation:'    '" myfile.tex
```

---

I've also achieved my secondary goal of having the `indent.log` file saved in the desired location by adding the following section to my `.vscode\settings.json` file:

```json
"latex-workshop.latexindent.args": [
  "-d"
  "-c",
  "%OUTDIR%/",
  "%TMPFILE%"
]
```

This ensures the log file is placed within the output folder specified by:

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%DIR%/build",
```

This approach keeps my root directory organized, preventing unwanted clutter.

I hope this information clarifies the message and provides an alternative solution for users who only need basic functionality from `latexindent.pl` within VS Code.